# Sustainsys Saml2 Authentication failed unclear message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, sustainsys-saml2

I'm using the Systainsys SAML2 owin library in a .Net 4.8. After enabling logging I get this response logged. I don't understand what the issue is I'm redacting some of the stuff in the SAML response JIC

Saml2 Authentication failed. The received SAML data is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Destination="https://####.####.com/Saml2/Acs" ID="_c68e19d777a7a13bab9ff8d54e83ad54" InResponseTo="id4cced0bf2ffe4967a605d630433a5b72" IssueInstant="2020-12-29T08:34:21Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml:Issuer>https://ut1-www.is.sg.######.com/_fed/1/244023058963</saml:Issuer>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <Reference URI="#_c68e19d777a7a13bab9ff8d54e83ad54">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>gDIpQQwjNoeuy99R70CK3foRdds=</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>quIekezIAu/n4BzOFuhFLqGhV4s80O0dPeogYufJq/oz6hxFqVETwnZ4ogd+62gyAX7EpRQ2q/NT
EdnnonD7RIVK89E5/K+LXjNWpXGxYFOmyrjUVCpWpo4WoNh720TkRwAAOnDSSnimb/EZf/c74dFp
4O5oNPC2r1uYYZ2ka6Zz0BcwnDIkFnJ60Q90ooJlYKZyBgGWpia7iyr3B61FCb/4bd6XWo5f3OZX
+mUPkacouj8nvYVAnbvOZZd+jXsOEkPvBCiCT+iEOrd4zzGkdPnowN9/eDljGYmBvT7GdqkrDIN6
2UMiBArIe0lk9LkhLNSHWl0o4Fd7ca6i96tZeA==</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>MIIDA....</X509Certificate>
         </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
   <samlp:Status>
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
   </samlp:Status>
   <saml:Assertion ID="_4c8ae5013fa6e1c8ba67d5274cec9bbd" IssueInstant="2020-12-29T08:34:21Z" Version="2.0">
      <saml:Issuer>https://ut1-www.is.sg.#####.com/_fed/1/244023058963</saml:Issuer>
      <saml:Subject>
         <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">######</saml:NameID>
         <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
            <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="id4cced0bf2ffe4967a605d630433a5b72" NotOnOrAfter="2020-12-29T08:39:21Z" Recipient="https://#####.#####.com/Saml2/Acs" />
         </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
      </saml:Subject>
      <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2020-12-29T08:34:21Z" NotOnOrAfter="2020-12-29T08:39:21Z">
         <saml:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml:Audience>https://####.#####.com/SAML2</saml:Audience>
         </saml:AudienceRestriction>
      </saml:Conditions>
      <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2020-12-29T08:34:21Z">
         <saml:AuthnContext>
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
         </saml:AuthnContext>
      </saml:AuthnStatement>
   </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Edit

After enabling the Katana logging I got this error

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'https://*****.soterion.com/SAML2'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'https://*****.soterion.com/Saml2' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) in C:\agent2_work\15\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens\Validators.cs:line 108
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateConditions(Saml2SecurityToken samlToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters) in C:\agent2_work\15\s\src\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml\Saml2\Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Owin library is very non-friendly when troubleshooting. Enable the Katana logging to get some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tokenvalidationparameters. value of Audiences would be entity ID of your application and then pass tokenvalidationparamter to validate.

```
TokenValidationParameter parameters = new TokenValidationParameters();
parameters.ValidAudiences = new string[] {entity ID of SP}
```